# How can I divide a decimalField with a float?

Tags: python, django

This is my model:

```
  class Assignment(models.Model):
        reiseziel = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
        datum = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
        fahrzeug = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='car', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', blank=True, null=True)
        ausland = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
        gruppe = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
        personen = models.IntegerField()
        reisepreis = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
        netto = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
        mwst = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.reiseziel

 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.netto = self.reisepreis / 1.19 
        self.mwst = self.reisepreis - self.netto
        super(Assignment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is the Error:

unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'

Comment: Can you also add the relevant fields in your model and the error that you are getting? Also some general description apart from the code is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert both values to the same type to make the division work. In your case the most feasible will be simply converting `float` 1.19 to `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal

# (...)
self.netto = self.reisepreis / Decimal(1.19)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It helped a lot!